# How can I change TakeProfit and StopLoss immidiatly after a new manual order is placed in MT4

Tags: mql

I want to create something like a listener on the "new order" event.
I am new to MQL and I'm trying to find what is the best way.
I current initial first version is a crude mix of arrays that hold the existing orders and the new orders and I loop between them in while (true) loop with a sleep.

But Ideally, I would like to have something similar to an event listener and when a new order is placed my code will be called and I will be able to do what I want.

So for example:

1. A new order is manually placed
2. My script "intercepts" it
3. Modifies the order and sets the stop loss and take profit that I want

What I do right now is this:

```
int STOP_LOSS=8;
int TAKE_PROFIT=16;
int MARGIN_TO_MOVE_SL=5;
int orders[];
int ordersBeingChecked[];
int openOrdersSize;

int start()
{
    
    int sleepTime=60000;//1 minute
    CloseDeals deals;
    while(true){
      
       deals.checkEntriesAndPositions();
       deals.updateOrders();
       Sleep(sleepTime);
    }
    return(0);
}

class CloseDeals{

   public:
      CloseDeals(){
         ArrayResize(orders,100);//initialize order array. arbitrary 100 orders size
      };
      
      void checkEntriesAndPositions() {
        int total=OrdersTotal();
        if (total==openOrdersSize) return;
        else {
          for(int i=total-1;i>=0;i--) {
            bool orderSelected=OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS);
            int ticketNumber=OrderTicket();
            bool orderIsNew = checkIfOrderIsNew(ticketNumber);

            if (orderIsNew){
              handleNewOrder();
            }
          }
        }
      }

      void handleNewOrder(){
         int type   = OrderType();
         if (type==OP_BUY){
            modifyBuy(TAKE_PROFIT,STOP_LOSS);
         }
         if (type==OP_SELL){
            modifySell(TAKE_PROFIT,STOP_LOSS);
         }
      }
}
```